# C# Custom Ribbon Error

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Im using the below code to show a button on my Home tab in outlook, but when i go into a new instance such as creating a new email i get an error because TabHome is no longer available

```
  <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
  <tab idMso="TabHome">
<group id="Phishing" label="Phishing">
  <button id="Phishing_Email" label="Phishing_Email" size="large" />
</group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

ive tried adding a try catch on:

```
  public Ribbon1()
    {
        try
        {
            GetCustomUI("Ribbon1");
        }


        catch (System.Exception e) { }

    }
```

but i cant seem to prevent this error can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The inspector window has a tab with the `TabNewMailMessage` idMso value. So, you need to return an appropriate `idMso` values depending on where your custom UI is going to be created.

The [GetCustomUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.getcustomui%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method provides the `RibbonID` parameter which you can use to identify where your custom UI is going to be loaded. Just try to debug the add-in and see possible values passed for inspectors and explorer windows.

And the last, you shouldn't invoke the `GetCustomUI` method in the code. Instead, it is called by the Office applications when the UI is going to be created.

Comment: but i only want it to show on idMso Home nothing else. How can i prevent this i am at a dead end

Comment: You should not return any ribbon XML for inspectors then. Check the RibbonID parameter passed to the 'GetCustomUI' method.

Comment: You talking about the second piece of code in the question? I've already got rid of that and there is still errors